# How do I handle uploading images of different size propotions using React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, image-resizing, image-manipulation

So I have been searching on internet, trying to find the best way to upload images of different sizes (width and height) but still be able to display them properly in a gallery type of thing.

An example of what I mean to do is the facebook gallery, where the all pictures are well aligned even though they are of different sizes (and none of them do look stretched or anything).

[image: Facebook gallery of images]

I know such image manipulations have been implemented before because many sites deal with images, but i can't seem to find any decent solutions on the open internet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add css to your react components.

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:230px;
  max-height:95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Help me understand, wouldn't this stretch badly some of the images?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to accomplish using css property background-image. Simply do not put images into img tag, but use a simple element such as div with the following styles:

```
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://your-image-url.com);
  background-size: cover;
}
```